# Jquery loop object within in an array loop - console.log gives value but HTML gives [object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array in JSON-format with objects in it like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'pete',
        age: 43,
        addresses : [ 
                        { street: 'Streetway 1', city: 'New York' }, 
                        { street: 'Waystraat 2', city: 'Washington' } 
                    ]
    },
    {
        name: 'harry',
        age: 23,
        addresses : [ 
                        { street: 'Laneway 23', city: 'unknown' } 
                    ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to show the data with jQuery, and use the `$.each` function like this:

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, person) {
    $('#myDiv').append("<p class='single-person'>"+person.name+" ("+person.age+"), cities: "+ $.each(person.addresses, function(j, address){ address.city });+"</p>");
});
```

The `person.name` and `person.age` work fine, but the cities are displayed as `[object Object]`. But, when I try to `console.log` or `alert` the cities instead, they turn up fine (not in an object).

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `+person.name (person.age)+` that is working?

Comment: $.each returns an Object.. What did you expect?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan typo, already editted it. Thanks for the heads-up tho!

Comment: @Jonasw I'm trying to just list the cities, like: `Cities: New York, Washington`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to *map and join* the streets to a string:

```
myArray.forEach(function(person) {
  $('#myDiv').append(
    `<p class='single-person'>
     ${person.name}(${person.age}),
     cities: ${person.addresses.map(a=>a.city).join(",")}
     </p>`
  );
});
```

The upper code uses template literals. You could also use "+sth+" instead of ${sth} ...
http://jsbin.com/pixogeciya/edit?output

Comment: I didn't know this was possible, really nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/xh5d2krg/ 
Basicly what you can do is save the cities in another Jquery element and then appending the HTML of this element to your current person element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = [
      {
          name: 'pete',
          age: 43,
          addresses : [ 
                          { street: 'Streetway 1', city: 'New York' }, 
                          { street: 'Waystraat 2', city: 'Washington' } 
                      ]
      },
      {
          name: 'harry',
          age: 23,
          addresses : [ 
                          { street: 'Laneway 23', city: 'unknown' } 
                      ]
      }
  ];
 $.each(json, function(i, person) {
    var cities = $("<span class='cities'></span>");
    $.each(person.addresses, function(j, address){ 
      cities.append(address.city);
    });
    $('#myDiv').append("<p class='single-person'>"+person.name+" ("+person.age+"), cities: "+  cities.html() +"</p>");
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=myDiv></div>
```